# How to use Post to get data from API?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a function which consumes Web API. This function works great for `GET` requests. However, I need to get some other resources from API which, according to API provider's docs, requires `POST` method. So I've simply changed HttpMethod from `Get` to `HttpMethod.Post`. When I call the API then I get `Error 400 Bad Request`.

**CallAPI**

```
private static async Task<T> CallAPI<T>(string endpoint, string accessToken)
{
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
   new Uri(ApiUri, endpoint));

   request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

   var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

   var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

   var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
   var responseObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream);

   return responseObject;
}
```

I call this API:

```
var result = await CallAPI<SomeDataModel>("cars/locations", accessToken);
```

Don't know where is a problem. It works great for GET as I said. Moreover, I don't understand why there's a need to use `POST` instead of `GET`to get data. I think it's against REST best-practices. According to provider's API docs, I don't need to attach any parameters to POST request, it's just raw endpoint. Anyways, I need to use POST here to get data.

Comment: Bad Request is constructed by the server. So without knowing anything about the server we can't help.

Comment: your server must allow "post" method

Comment: It's strange. Provider's API says in theirs docs that POST must be used in this case and now seems their server doesn't allow it..

Comment: Is it only this enpoint that fails or may there be a problem with Authentication/Authorization?

Comment: You should mention the API being used, someone may have knowledge as to how to use it. Also when making a POST request a body is usually required even if it is not used.

Comment: _"Provider's API says in theirs docs"_ - are those docs online and public? Can you link to the respective paragraph/section?

Comment: @Fildor no, auth works fine, no problems at all. Can't send docs since it's for private use only

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm for now I only add this as content: `request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>{["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",["scope"] = Scopes});`. How should I add empty body?

Comment: That content is setting the body. If this is an internal company API you should talk to the creators for usage examples. If this is a third party API you should be able to inform us what that API is.

Comment: It's internal API so I can't. But thanks for guidance

Comment: Is this an OAuth request? It kind of feels like it.

Comment: Yes, it is OAuth

Comment: In that cases you might be missing the client id and secret in the body/content. I see you only provide the grant type and scope.

Comment: The above function calls API. I also created another function which gets token and there's secret id and client id. How can I add empty body to Content shown above? Can I hardcode it somehow?

Comment: You can, request.Content = new StringContent(""); However, it would be best to talk to the API creators of what they may need for the Post data.